# Lagom Framework - How to generate an API skeleton from Swagger api.json file

Tags: scala, sbt, swagger, spray, lagom

I am migrating from a [Spray Framework](http://spray.io/) (version 1.3.X) based JSON REST API service documented with Swagger ([spray-swagger](https://github.com/gettyimages/spray-swagger/tree/8173a2006b3bdc1f8be02f848c789d38289e2d21) version 1.3 or 1.4) to [Lagom Framework](https://www.lagomframework.com/). I have the Swagger api.json file that documents all the endpoints (path, description, GET/POST, etc) and I was wondering if I could generate a skeleton (like a bunch of empty API endpoint stubs) for a Lagom microservice from the Spray Swagger API Documentation.

https://github.com/lagom

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way involves using the [Lagom code generator](https://www.lagomframework.com/blog/announcing-lagom-code-generator.html) available at: https://github.com/lagom/sbt-lagom-descriptor-generator

Example project:

https://github.com/ignasi35/lagom-pet-store/

Additional details:

https://github.com/lagom/lagom/pull/375

https://github.com/lagom/lagom/issues/280